# mysql_connect error message

Tags: php, mysql

The mysql error message "Database connection cannot be established" is intermittently showing whenever I call the config file in my page. What seems to be the problem in my code?

///-- config.php --////

```
$hostname = "localhost";
$database = "db";
$db_user = "root";
$db_pass = "pass";  

session_start();

try {
    $conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("Database connection cannot be established.");
    if(!$conn)
    {
    $_SESSION['errormsg'] = "Connection failed.";
    exit();
    }
    else
    {
    mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception: ", $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Comment: ask mysql  $conn = mysql_connect($hostname,$db_user,$db_pass) or die("Database connection cannot be established. ".mysql_error());

Comment: If it doesn't happen on every call then it's a network connectivity issue, not a problem in the code. It can be that the MySQL server is overloaded and it cannot accept new connections, it can be a routing problem, it can be a network congestion, it can be a defective cable, it can be anything.

Comment: @axiac `defective cable` on `localhost`?

Comment: And as a side note, please read about PDO (or mysqli) from php.net - mysql* functions are deprecated and you really shouldn't use them

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky If the MySQL server is on `localhost` then none of the reasons I suggested stands.

Answer (score 2):

```
die("Database connection cannot be established."); // big deal?
```

Only tells you what you ***already*** know.

```
die(mysql_error());
```

Tells you what you ***need*** to know.

P.S: ***intermittently*** and ***whenever*** are contradictory, please update your question to remove the confusion and stress on one.

Comment: Good remark about **intermittently** and **whenever**.